# Transform XML request to Map<String,Object>

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, xml-parsing

I have a Situation, Where in our API, consumes XML/JSON and return back with any of it. 
In Spring, if we have Map in @RequestBody then automatically JSON object get de-serialized in Map. But in case of XML this statement is not true by default. 
Can we have any mechanism to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use Content Negotiation. Here are the links [Content Negotiation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc)
& https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml